# How to iterate alphabet in a loop and compare to list

Tags: python, algorithm, mpi

I am using MPI to build a password cracker for my assignment, and chose to use python with which i haven't used before. It is not a complex all i am doing is assuming the password to be  5 characters long and only characters, and i will have hardcoded password within the program to compare it with.

Now i am saving my `password = list("aaamm")` as such and have a method called cracker as

```
cracker(password, alphabet, thispass, position):
    password = original password, alphabet = map(chr, range(97, 123))
```

and, this pass will be initially be equal = `list("aaaaa")`

Since i haven't used python before i am having hard time to develop an algorithm that will check `thispass[0] == password[0]` and if they are equal i move to next position that is this `pass[1] == password[1]`, BUT if not then increment "a' to "b" and compare it against `password[0]`.

I am also having position in my cracker function which is for MPI processes, i am going have 2 processes working on position (=0 i.e. "a" of this pass) while the first process will be checking from "a" to "m" and the second one from "n" to "z".

I have already split the size of alphabet on the other side of the program from where i call cracker function.

My main problem is comparing, `mypass[0]` to `password[0]` ideally would be nice to have this within loop but cannot determine how to have a loop that will start from "a" through to whatever range of alphabet is.

This is my first time so do forgive me if its all messy above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning comparing:  In Python you can compare lots of things, even whole lists, even nested ones, by using the `==` operator (and of course `!=`):

```
a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
b = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
c = [ 'x', 'b', 'y' ]
if a == b:  # will be true
  …
if a == c:  # will be false
  …
if a[1] == c[1]:  # will be true
  …
```

This also works with literals:

```
if ([ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 'f', 'g' ] ==
    [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd', 'e' ], 'f', 'g' ]):  # will be true
  …
```

Concerning the checking loop, I'd propose this:

```
if len(password) != len(thispass):
  … # ignore attempts with wrong length, e. g. return False or similar
for position in range(len(password)):
  while thispass[position] != password[position]:
    try:
      thispass[position] = alphabet[alphabet.index(thispass[position]) + 1]
    except IndexError:  # no further alphabet element for this position?
      thispass[position] = alphabet[0]  # set to first element of alphabet (wrap)
```

This way you find the password by testing and modifying each position until it matches.  It will not terminate if the password to match contains elements outside the alphabet.

Comment: thanks a lot, just want to clear it a bit more, say thispass="aaa" and password="baa" so is the following true, execution enters for loop(first round) while is true since a!=b and in the try block thispass[positiom] is now equal to "b" and execution back to for loop(second round)? and again, thanks a lot mate

Comment: If `thispass` is `aaa`, then the first round of the `while` loop will compare `a` and `b`, find it different and then increase the `a` to `b` (next in the alphabet).  The next round will find `b` and `b` equal, so the while loop will terminate and the next round of the `for` loop will start (with a new entering of the `while` loop for the next character).